# Change UINavigationBar Font SIze for Select Views

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I know how to change the UINavigationBar's title font properties by using this code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];
```

However, I am finding that when I change the font size in this way it effects all views, not just the view in which I am implementing the above code. The problem is, I want to change the size for just 2 views that have long titles. The other views (including the root view) I wish to retain the default setting for font size. I've tried changing the font size back to normal in the `viewDidLoad` method using the above code, but it does not work.

Is there a way to change the title font size for just certain views? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should call that code in each view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method. When you set it in `viewDidLoad`, the setting gets overridden by the next view controller's actions. You might also have to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the navigationBar to refresh it (although I don't believe so).

Like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f],
              UITextAttributeFont,
              nil]];
}
```

Comment: `viewWillAppear` did the trick. Using `viewDidAppear` showed the text size changing because it was waiting until the view was completely pushed to the window. Thanks!

Comment: At least on iOS 7 you can implement this line in the `viewDidLoad` method